# How to search/replace a line "export DB= $old value " with $new value in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, scripting

How to search/replace a line `"export DB= $old value "` with `$new` value in shell

i tried before with

```
sed -i '/export DB=/c\'export DB=$new value'' $filename
```

and

```
sed -e "s/oldvalue/$new value/"
```

Comment: Please clarify, you need to search and replace using variables, or `$` is literally a part of pattern?

Comment: Can you show your inputfile, and the result of `echo "(old, new)=($old, $new)` (as en edit of your question)